# Refreshing the Jquery function upon changing Select item

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

```
 <select class="brandselect selectpicker">
      <option>A</option>
      <option>B</option>
      <option>C</option>
 </select>

 <select class="modelselect selectpicker">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
 </select>
```

I have two dropdown lists that are using [Jquery Selectric](http://lcdsantos.github.io/jQuery-Selectric/demo.html) plugin to style the select items.

The second dropdown is dynamically generated upon the selection of the first dropdown.
The following functions of the plugin works when the first dropdown selection is made. It gets refreshed.

I need that function to refresh the plugin for all dropdowns again, upon the selection of the second dropdown items. But it doesn't refresh and it goes back to the default styling of the dropdowns.

How am I suppose to keep these functions alive once it runs one time?

```
   $('.brandselect').change(function() {
           setTimeout(function() {
        $('selectpicker').selectric('refresh');
        }, 500);
    });

   $('.modelselect').change(function() {
           setTimeout(function() {
        $('.selectpicker').selectric('refresh');
        }, 500);
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .on (Event delegation)

Place the event on the parent of the select boxes:

```
<div id="parent">
 <select class="brandselect selectpicker">
  <option>A</option>
  <option>B</option>
  <option>C</option>
 </select>

 <select class="modelselect selectpicker">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
  <option>3</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

and your JS:

**updated Thanks -Eduardo Quintana**

```
 $('#parent').on('change', '.brandselect', function() {
       setTimeout(function() {
    $('selectpicker').selectric('refresh');
    }, 500);
});

 $('#parent').on('change', '.modelselect', function(){
       setTimeout(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectric('refresh');
    }, 500);
};
```

Comment: $('#parent').on('change', '.brandselect', ...  $('.selectpicker').selectric('refresh');

Comment: Now it doesn't load even after the first dropdown selection.

Comment: Hey @Talha Please make a JSFiddle so we can see the states that the html goes through when selectric messes with it.

Comment: Jsfiddle won't work because plugin changes the syntax. But if you want to take a look at it here http://otoneo.com/ you need to click the big blue button on the left of two buttons. And the opening modal window will show you plugin styled dropdowns.

Comment: If you choose the second dropdown after choosing an item from the first, the styling will disappear

Comment: its after a ajax call @EduardoQuintana  - the question is worded badly.

Comment: Well your solution works in static HTML. BUt I guess my backend changes the html syntax. And that's why it doesn't work.
This [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0eb2jffj57)
becomes this [link](http://awesomescreenshot.com/0af2jffn1c)

Comment: Yes @Talha - you need to capture the callback event of the call that updates the modal page. `$(document).ajaxComplete(function() { console.log('yoyo'); $('.selectpicker').selectric('refresh');});`  i was trying this but am not succeeding yet.

Comment: @Talha In your main page inside the do postback event try changing to this after the submit. 
`function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) { 
.....
        theForm.submit();
        $('.selectpicker').selectric('refresh');
    }
}`